# Interfaces for injectable services in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection, interface, duck-typing

I'm new to AngularJS. From what I understand, the whole point of dependency injection is so that the dependency can be easily swapped with a "similar" dependency later and the code still works the same. With "similar", it is usually meant that the dependency implements some kind of an interface.

If I'm writing a controller and my co-worker is writing a service which I'm going to use in my controller, how can I make sure that the service he is making for me has all the things I need? In a traditional OO language, his service would be a class implementing an interface, which would force him to implement certain methods. But how can this be done in angularJS? Would I have to check if the service has properties for all the methods I want and that the `__proto__` for all those properties is `Function.prototype`? And to check the what these methods return, do I have call them with mock objects and then inspect the returned object?
Or is there a better recommended way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That may be a feature of DI, but the point is to be able to see where your dependencies are coming from explicitly rather than them being staged over some magical global like window.

JavaScript has no implicit way of enforcing interfaces. Your coworker would create either a service or factory that provides an object with functions and properties attached to it. Again, those functions can return whatever the want and you do not have a means to enforce what they return.

If you want to make sure your coworker is returning what you expect, it might be a good idea to write unit tests and use ngMock.

Additionally, attach to `prototype` and not `__proto__`.